# Create folder tree, Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, treeview

I'm new to C# and Windows Forms and want to create a simple UI like this.

[image]

I have the following arrays:

```
string [] projects;
string [] subjects;  
string [] experiments;
string [] scans;
string [] files;
```

Edit: Each child element has info indicating to which parent it belongs (which may make this more suitable for an arrangement of `Subject [] subjects, Experiment [] experiments`, etc.)

And the Windows Forms component must work this way

```
projects  (<- when clicked should show the string array of projects)
|
|--- subjects (<- when clicked should show the string array of subjects)
        |
        |---experiments (<- when clicked should show the string array of experiments)
               |
               |--- scans (<- when clicked should show the string array of scans)
                      |
                      |----files (<- when clicked should show the string array of files)
```

I think the [TreeView component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) fits the bill, but as I'm new to Windows Forms (and what to get this thing done ***fast***), I thought I'd better check in SO first.

Is TreeView the appropriate way to implement this UI?

Comment: treeview is fine for that. See http://www.dotnetperls.com/treeview for usage. But your array layout is "unsuitable" because it contains no information about the actual parent element - better have a look at the composite-pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

Comment: Thanks, I actually have info indicating at which parent component each child belongs, I think this would make the arrangement suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The Treeview is the best component for your need.

You can also use this component with a XML file.

For more information, check these links:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/treeview

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.treeview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)